# Rapidxml is not compiling on Visual Studio 2010. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, rapidxml

I am working on switching XML parsers from TinyXml to RapidXml in our codebase.

However, RapidXml does not seem to compile with Visual Studio 2010.

Basically, in the header file I am doing

```
#define RAPIDXML_NO_EXCEPTIONS
#include "RapidXml/rapidxml.hpp"
using namespace rapidxml;
```

And in the implementation

```
xml_document<> xmlDoc;
xmlDoc.parse<0>(filestring);
```

And right there, on my second line of code, Visual Studio says

> c:\users\name\development\rapidxml\rapidxml.hpp(420): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'memory'
>   1>          c:\users\name\development\rapidxml\rapidxml.hpp(418) : while compiling class template member function 'rapidxml::xml_node<> *rapidxml::memory_pool::allocate_node(rapidxml::node_type,const Ch *,const Ch *,size_t,size_t)'
>   1>          with
>   1>          [
>   1>              Ch=char
>   1>          ]
>   1>          c:\users\name\development\rapidxml\rapidxml.hpp(1359) : see reference to class template instantiation 'rapidxml::memory_pool' being compiled
>   1>          with
>   1>          [
>   1>              Ch=char
>   1>          ]
>   1>          c:\users\name\development\xmlresource.cpp(70) : see reference to class template instantiation 'rapidxml::xml_document<>' being compiled

It is the end of a long coding day and this is about it for today. Do you knowledgeable people out there have any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my actual problem:

As part of some memory debugging, I overloaded new with a version that does not support placement new. However, rapidxml does require placement new to work, so that is where those errors came from. Oh my.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some sample code I use, perhaps it will help?

```
   #include <rapidxml.hpp>

   rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
   doc.parse<rapidxml::parse_no_data_nodes | rapidxml::parse_trim_whitespace>( buffer );

   rapidxml::xml_node<>* root;
   root = doc.first_node();
   if ( root )
   {
      rapidxml::xml_node<>* cur_node;

      cur_node = root->first_node( "SessionLoginDeadline" );
      if ( cur_node )
         SessionLoginDeadline = cur_node->value();

      cur_node = root->first_node( "Port" );
      if ( cur_node )
         Port = stringTo<unsigned short>( cur_node->value() );

      cur_node = root->first_node( "MaximumAllowedClients" );
      if ( cur_node )
         MaximumAllowedClients = stringTo<unsigned short>( cur_node->value() );
   }
```